# document.getElementById returning [object HTMLDivElement]

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to develop some script which toggles the `display` property of the css linked to my HTML document. This is in order to show/hide the navbar in the document. But when I run this script, the console shows `[object HTMLDivElement]` for the `document.getElementById` which is really confusing.

I don't think this is that of a big deal, but my head is kinda cloudy now...

```
        function navbarCollapse() {
        var navbarCollapsable = document.getElementById('nav-collapsable');

        var navbarCollapsableVisibility = navbarCollapsable.style.display;
        var invisible = "none";

        if (navbarCollapsableVisibility !== invisible) {
            navbarCollapsableVisibility = invisible;
        } else {
            navbarCollapsableVisibility = "block";
        };
    }
```

Comment: Don't cache `navbarCollapsableVisibility` or else you're assigning primitives, not references and nothing will happen.

Comment: Did it @AndrewLi but same results. Nothing changed...

Answer (score 3):

This is what should be returned. Please refer to MDN's docs for document.getElementById:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

> Return Value
>
> element
>
> is a reference to an Element object, or null if an element with the 
>   specified ID is not in the document.

Comment: No problem, dude.

Comment: The element does exist and I've read that resource as well. But still no results...

Comment: [object HTMLDivElement] is the representation of the Element Object that is being returned...

Answer (score 1):

Just solved it. As @AronF pointed out, `[object HTMLDivElement]` is what I'm supposed to be seeing. The issue was that I should not have been storing the `navbarCollapsable.style.display` in a var for some reason. Did this and got through:

```
function navbarCollapse() {
        var navbarCollapsable = document.getElementById('nav-collapsable');

        if (navbarCollapsable.style.display !== "none") {
            navbarCollapsable.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            navbarCollapsable.style.display = "block";
        };
    }
```